# Is there a word or phrase to describe unnecessary details?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Preferably in a more idiomatic kind of way.

I was thinking 'chaff', as in 'to separate the wheat from the chaff' (to separate the important details from the unnecessary ones), but am I right in thinking that that's used more in terms of people?

Comment: Yes, but it's also fine used in your context.

Answer (score 2):

*The minutiae* is one possibility:

> **the minutiae** noun [ plural ]
>
> small and often not important details:
>
> - The committee studied the minutiae of the report for hours.
> - Comedy is so often based on the minutiae of everyday life.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minutiae)

Answer (score 1):

Superfluous

adjective

> unnecessary, especially through being more than enough.

*The purchaser should avoid asking for superfluous information*